# char array gets ghost data (arduino)

Tags: arduino

I'm setting an array with data from an EEPROM.
As you can see in the code below I instantiate an array, loop 16 times and fill the array with data read from the EEPROM. 
I've tested the data that is read from the EEPROM which is correct, but if I print the array after the loop I get 18 characters. I can't find out where the data is coming from. Any ideas?

```
void send_eeprom_data()
{
  char eeprom_data[16];
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    eeprom_data[i] = read_eeprom(8, i);
  }
  Serial.print(eeprom_data);
}

/* READ AND TRANSFER FUNCTIONS */
char spi_transfer(volatile char data) {
  SPDR = data;
  while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)))
  {
  };
  return SPDR;
}

byte read_eeprom(int ss, int address) {
  int data;
  digitalWrite(ss, LOW);
  spi_transfer(READ);
  spi_transfer((char)(address));
  data = spi_transfer(0xFF);
  digitalWrite(ss, HIGH);
  return data;
}
```

## update

I changed the code to the following:

```
void send_eeprom_data()
{
  char eeprom_data[16];
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    eeprom_data[i] = 'a';
  }
  Serial.print(eeprom_data);
}
```

Ouput:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaûz
```

(16 a's)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

print most probably expects a zero-terminated string (nearly everything in the C universe does). You did not end your string with a '\0', so it keeps on printing after your 16 characters until it finds one.

PS this is a pure C question.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this works when I use `eeprom_data[i] = 'a';` but when I use `eeprom_data[i] = read_eeprom(8, i);` it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: That seems to have nothing to do with your original question, and as is it is unanswerable: what is the effect, what do you think it should have been?

Comment: How does it have nothing to do with my original answer? I'm filling an array with data from the read_eeprom function, but when I print it, it appends two characters. I expect to get a 16 character output, instead I get 18, where are the last two coming from. If that makes any sense.

Comment: That is the question I answered: you did not terminate the string. Append a '\0' one position beyond the last character. If you don't, you will get funny results.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I did that and it worked when the array had just a's in it, but when I filled the array with the function results it would't work. I added `eeprom_data[17] = '\0'`.

Comment: @JeroenRietveld In the C language, there is actually no such thing as a `string` data type, and thus nothing inherently contained in a "string" to tell the function using it what length it should be, other than a terminating NULL char. C only uses a pointer to the first entry of an array of `char` data. This is unlike some other languages, e.g. many implementations of Pascal, where the current length of a string is prefixed as the first data unit of the "string" array.

Comment: @JeroenRietveld As you have defined your array as having length 16 characters, the last valid entry in any case is `eeprom_data[15]`. Writing to `eeprom_data[17]` is essentially overwriting some other variable stored in memory, that is a really naughty thing to do.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Ahhh, my bad, I did define the array to have a length of 17 (eeprom_data[17]), but `eeprom_data[17] = '\0'` should've been `eeprom_data[16] = '\0'`. Thanks a lot for all the answers it works now :). And it makes sense why it didn't at first.

Answer (score 4):

Even though your declare your variable eeprom_data to be an array of type char (with 16 elements), the variable "eeprom_data" itself is simply a pointer to the first elemt in this array. When you pass this pointer to Serial.print(), this function knows nothing about how long the array is, and as @Wouter-van-Ooijen has pointed out keeps reading (i.e. incrementing the pointer) until it finds a "zero" character (the byte value 0). This appears* to be the third character after the end of character array, but it could easily be a lot later, and therefore keeps printing these extra values it finds.

*) as an aside note: I said "appears", because there may very well be other non-zero characters that aren't printed in the terminal, simply because they are non-printable/control characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes sense. It's working now:)